# File » Revert to Previous: Where are versions stored?

Tags: applescript, time-machine, automator, textedit, history

Over time you learn some tricks on your Macbook. TextEdit has this really [neat feature](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-and-restore-past-versions-of-documents-mh40710/mac), where it takes care of autosave and allows you to revert to nearly any prior edit stage of a document.

**Question:** Is there a way to save all the previous versions of a .txt document accessible through this feature, ideally with a datestamp for each?

Perhaps using some sort of Automator or AppleScript?

​

[image]

Comment: The copies of documents available from that menu option are stored in `/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/../..` prior to **macOS Catalina** and in `/System/Volumes/Data/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/../..` in **macOS Catalina** and have names such as `BD51C74A-41CF-493B-A97C-9615F87F2D23.ext` where `.ext` is that for the designated file type. `.DocumentRevisions-V100` is hidden and owned by `root`, so not directly accessible by a normal user from the _command line_ without the use of `sudo` or  equivalence.

Comment: Thanks! (havent tried yet) where did you learn this  ̶s̶̶t̶i̶f̶f̶  stuff? I kinda wish I knew bash but all i know is eco -e and ls